# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my edit page. When I submit I get this error:

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I have no clue where it comes from as I am pretty new to Laravel.

routes(web.php):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::get('/', 'ProjectController@index');

Route::get('/projects/{id}', 'ProjectController@show');
Route::post('/create','ProjectController@store');
Route::get('/create', 'ProjectController@create');
Route::get('/projects/{id}/delete', 'ProjectController@destroy');
Route::put('/edit','ProjectController@update');
Route::get('/projects/{id}/edit', 'ProjectController@edit');

});
```

Controller:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('project.edit',[

            'project' => Project::find($id)
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $project = Project::find($request->id);
        $project->project_name = $request->input('project_name');
        $project->client = $request->input('client');
        $project->description = $request->input('description');
        $project->time_span = $request->input('time_span');
        $project->text_report = $request->input('text_report');
        $project->created_by = $request->input('created_by');

        $project->save();

        return  redirect('/')->with('success', 'Project aangepast');
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You currently have the update controller method being called via a PUT method. Either change the form to use PUT or change the line Route::put('/edit','ProjectController@update'); to Route::post('/edit','ProjectController@update');

Comment: thanks for the comment Petay, but when i replace put with post and get a new error returned :Creating default object from empty value

Comment: When you find the Project, you should also check the find() return a valid Project object, not a null.

Comment: Have you considered using a `resource` route/controller? You could just use `Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectController');` to have all necessary routes set up. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can handle this:

1. If you insist on using `PUT` you can change the form action to `POST` and add a hidden `method_field` that has a value `PUT`and a hidden csrf field (if you are using blade then you just need to add `@csrf_field` and `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`). This way the form would accept the request.
2. You can simply change the route and form method to `POST`. It will work just fine since you are the one defining the route and not using the resource group.

Comment: i did both of these methods, and returns Creating default object from empty value

Comment: @JohnSmith2521 try to pass the project id just like you did for the edit
as such `Route::put('/edit/{id}','ProjectController@update');` 
The problem is that it is not finding a project with the provided id.
The route itself is now working well. This means that you are not sending the id or the request is missing. You can check the request in the inspect elements networking headers.

Comment: i've added the id to the route and it returns a 404 page not found

Comment: @JohnSmith2521 How did you redirect to the route? is the Url correct?

Comment: @JohnSmith2521 also did you change the route action?

Comment: Route::post('/edit/{id}','ProjectController@update'); this is my route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190074/discussion-between-khaldoun-nd-and-johnsmith2521).

Comment: Works for me using laravel v8.

Answer (score 62):

I know this is not the solution to OPs post. However, this post is the first one indexed by Google when I searched for answers to this error. For this reason I feel this will benefit others.

The following error...

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported
>   methods: GET, HEAD.

was caused by not clearing the routing cache

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: It wasn't _caused_ by not clearing the cache. It some circumstances it may resolve the issue.

Comment: @stoi2m1I had a similiar problem and only solution was rebooting vagrant. Not a single artisan and composer command didn't help.

Comment: If you `php artisan route:cache` the request will be routed from cached routes right and if you `php artisan route:clear` the request will be routed from `web.php`. Caching routes is for performance optimization when in production. During development you must not cache routes otherwise you will have to `route:clear` and `route:cache` with every change which is not desirable

Answer (score 18):

In my case just run the command and worked like charm.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 15):

add  @method('PUT') on the form

exp:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">

@csrf  

@method('PUT')



</form>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm , i'm using a crm with some custom form processor, i was wondering if this works, and it did, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 7):

I just removed the slash at the end of url and it began working...
`/managers/games/id/push/` to:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "/managers/games/id/push",
```

This may have to do with upgrading to laravel 5.8?

Comment: In my case, I think there was some redirect somewhere that was enforcing no-trailing-slash - unfortunately that redirect was also converting my POST request into a GET requests, therefore throwing a "GET method is not supported" error, and baffling me... Removing the trailing slash made the problem go away

Answer (score 6):

I've seen your code in web.php as follows:

```
Route::post('/edit/{id}','ProjectController@update');
```

Step 1: remove the {id} random parameter so it would be like this:

`Route::post('/edit','ProjectController@update');`

Step 2: Then remove the @method('PUT') in your form, so let's say we'll just plainly use the **POST** method

Then how can I pass the ID to my method?

Step 1: make an input field in your form with the hidden attribute
for example

`<input type="hidden" value="{{$project->id}}" name="id">`

Step 2: in your **update** method in your controller, fetch that ID
for example:

```
$id = $request->input('id');
```

then you may not use it to find which project to edit

```
$project = Project::find($id)
//OR
$project = Project::where('id',$id);
```

Comment: it still returns : The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: please complete the error message or at least give me a screenshot of your form and  the error message

Comment: I still can't see the codes of your "view" that contains the form

Comment: i cant edit it in, it says i have too much code for the amount of text i got

Comment: send me a screenshot of your controller and view to my email, vtvc17@gmail.com so I can help you, thank you :)

Comment: I've seen your error you have your /edit route to be on the POST request, your code is "Route::post('/edit/{id}','ProjectController@update');"

Comment: what do i need to change exactly?

Comment: ive used the second step like this $project = Project::find($request->$id);
        $project->project_name = $request->input('project_name');
        $project->client = $request->input('client');
        $project->description = $request->input('description');

Comment: I re-edited it, the answer had some cropped codes, fixed it now

Comment: nice, that would do also

Answer (score 4):

Hi you dont have to write all the routes just follow the conventions  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers
check : **Actions Handled By Resource Controller** section

Since HTML forms can't make PUT, PATCH, or DELETE requests, you will need to add a hidden _method. When posting a data from n laravel you have to use,

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
@method('PUT')
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to fix this is to add this to your form.

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

then the update method will be like this :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
    $project->name = $request->name;
    $project->description = $request->description;

    $post->save();
}
```

Comment: You can also use the blade syntax like so {{ method_field('PUT') }}  intead of  using THML input tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just name your routes.

```
Route::post('/{page}/articles', AddArticle::class)->name('addArticle');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Route::group, with a vendor plugin like LaravelLocalization (from MCAMARA), you need to put POST routes outside of this group.  I've experienced problems with POST routes using this plugin and I did solved right now by putting these routes outside Route::group..

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due tho the `-` in the link.

My link was sale/change-satus then when I submitted the `form` with `method="POST"`, it was transformed to `GET` (i don't know why) then the body was empty.

My solution was to rename the url like  this

```
Route::post('/sale/status/change', [SalesController::class, 'changeStat']);
```

Answer (score -2):

**The problem happens for both PUT and DELETE requests**

So you have laravel routes like that

```
Route::put('/calendars/{id}', 'CalendarController@update')->name('calendar.update');
Route::delete('/calendars/{id}', 'CalendarController@destroy')->name('calendar.destroy');
```

And you try to call that routes using Ajax like that

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/calendars/" + eventObj.id,
  type: "DELETE" 
});
```

and get error..

The solution:

Convert your type to POST and add _method key in your data object.

So the right approach for our DELETE request would be

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/calendars/" + eventObj.id,
  data: {
    _method:"DELETE"
  },
  type: "POST" 
});
```

Same thing applies for PUT requests as well. Do not forget to add _method key in your data object. E.x.

```
data: {
  'title': 'Meeting',
  'location': 'Zoom',
  '_method': 'PUT'
}
```