# PUT method not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6 to make an edit form. Apparently, this is a prevalent problem, and I looked up here how can I solve it, I tried putting hidden csrf fields in 5 ways and I run with the same error every time, so IDK if those solutions are deprecated for Laravel 6 or I am doing something wrong.

**edit.blade.php**

```php
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->edit}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ $post->email }}" class="form-control"
               id="exampleFormControlInput1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $post->name }}" class="form-control"
               id="exampleFormControlInput2" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Image</label>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            @if($post->image)
                <img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="/images/{{ $post->image }}"/>
            @endif
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="image" value="{{ $post->image }}"
               id="exampleFormControlInput3">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**PostsController.php**

```
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view ('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        $post->update($request->all());
        $post->name = $request->name;
        $post->email = $request->email;

        if(Input::hasFile('image')){
        $file = Input::file('image');
        $path = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = public_path(). '/images/';
        $filename = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

       //then proceeded to save
       $post->image = $destinationPath.$filename;
       $post->save();
       }

       else
        $post->save();

    return redirect('posts.all');
    }
```

My routes, in case it's necessary

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

These are the other ways I tried to write the csrf field.

Way 1:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Way 2:

```
@csrf_field
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Way 3:

```
@csrf
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

Way 4:

```
@csrf
@method('PUT')
```

All of these lead me to the same error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Comment: @CaddyDZ I checked that specific question before posting this, nothing worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to replace this :

```php
<form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->edit}}"
```

with this :

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.update', [$post->id]) }}"
```

I think that you are trying to Post on the /posts/ route without any arguments as $post->edit might not return the id of the post :)

Comment: Was writing this exact answer xD, you beat me to it

Comment: yeah it was that, idk why it would show that message instead of something like I don't have an edit variable defined lmao