# Form error in Laravel blade. Is "class" or "id" or something the cause?

Tags: php, laravel

I don’t know why this form causes an error.  *THIS ISSUE IS NOT RELATED TO ROUTE.  Please read my question thoroughly.

> “The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD.”

What does makes it happen?  The first one here works well.

But the second one will happen the error.  Which class or id should I remove?

```
//OK
<form action="{{ route('contact_confirm') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" type="submit">Send</button></div>
    <input id="title" type="text" name = "title"  />
    <input id="title" type="text" name = "body"  />
</form>

//NG
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <form id="contactForm" 　action="{{ route('contact_confirm') }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                    <label>TITLE</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="title" type="text" name = "title" placeholder="Title" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name." />
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                    <label>CONTENTS</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" name ="body" placeholder="Message" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

PHP
web.php

```
Route::post('contact/confirm', 'ContactsController@confirm')->name('contact_confirm');
```

Comment: Can you show your routes as well? Seems like the route method might be wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Comment: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: It seems a similar to the post you presented.  Route(web.php) is not related to this problem. it causes in blade file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `post` route could be missing.

Verify in your `routes/web.php` file that you have something that looks like this:

```
Route::post('your/route', ...)->name('contact_confirm');
```

More info on routing can be [found here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#named-routes).

Comment: Thank you for answering it. But this issue is not related to "routing". because the code I posted works correctly.