# Update function keep getting this error: The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, crud

I kept getting this error when trying to use the update function in edit view, but not sure how to fix it.

```
       Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
       The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

here is the edit blade:

```
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route("course.update", [auth()->user()->username, $course->title. $course->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
```

here is the web.php:

```
      Route::get('/{user}/edit_{course}', 'CoursesController@edit')->name('course.edit');
      Route::patch('/{user}/update_{course}', 'CoursesController@update')->name('course.update');
```

the update url only shows like this, without the variables {course}:

```
      /{user}/update_
```

edit url works fine, using the same format. but the $course data doesn't seem passing into the edit view:

```
      {{ route("course.edit", [auth()->user()->username, $course->title. $course->id]) }}
```

here is the controller:

```
      public function edit(Course $course) {
        return view('courses.edit', compact('course'));
      }

      public function update(UpdateCourseRequest $request, Course $course) {
        $course->update($request->all());
        if (count($course->course_images) > 0) {
           foreach ($course->course_images as $media) {
              if (!in_array($media->file_name, $request->input('course_images', []))) {
               $media->delete();
           }
         }
       }
        $media = $course->course_images->pluck('file_name')->toArray();
        foreach ($request->input('course_images', []) as $file) {
            if (count($media) === 0 || !in_array($file, $media)) {
               $course->addMedia(storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $file))->toMediaCollection('course_images');
               }
            }
        return view('courses.index', compact('course'));
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Comment: hmm still not quite sure. I'm still getting the same error when replaced the patch method with the hidden input:    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 0):

When generating routes, the second parameter is an associative array. Usually you don't pass id's or strings into routes, but simply models and let `Model Binding` do the rest.

```
{{ route("course.update", ['user' => auth()->user(), 'course' => $course]) }}
```

Comment: It's giving me this error now, after I changed it:   Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Missing required parameters for [Route: course.update] [URI: {user}/update_{course}].

Comment: if you changed the route to  {user]/update/{course} would it work? i'm in doubt if something in your url structure is breaking it, you have course and user sent with it

Comment: I gave up, rewrote another version following the resource controller's format, not ideal but at least works.