# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel. I'm facing **Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.** error while submiting a form. Please help me to solve.

My coding is...

**student_edit.balde.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample view</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="images_update" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="com-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $student['id'] }}">
                <label>Name:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter the name" class="form-control"
                value="{{ $student['name'] }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter the email" class="form-control"
                value="{{ $student['email'] }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">  
                <label>Mobile:</label>
                <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter the mobile number" class="form-control"
                value="{{ $student['mobile'] }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.php**

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;

Route::get('/images', [TestController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/images', [TestController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/images/{id}', [TestController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('/images_update', [TestController::class, 'update']);
```

Comment: Try changing `action="images_update"` to `action="/images_update"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, try changing the form action line to the following:

```
<form action="/images_update" method="post">
```

Please also be aware that you can use [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes) Within Laravel (I have included an example of their usage below). These provide you with access to the route helper, which will prevent the need for you to manually enter the URL for each page.

**student_edit.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sample view</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="{{ route('images.update') }}" method="post">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="com-md-4">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $student['id'] }}">
                  <label>Name:</label> 
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter the name" class="form-control"
                     value="{{ $student['name'] }}">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter the email" class="form-control"
                     value="{{ $student['email'] }}">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">  
                  <label>Mobile:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter the mobile number" class="form-control"
                     value="{{ $student['mobile'] }}">
               </div>
               <div class="form-group"> 
                  <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;

Route::get('/images', [TestController::class, 'index'])->name('images.home');
Route::post('/images', [TestController::class, 'store'])->name('images.store');
Route::get('/images/{id}', [TestController::class, 'show'])->name('images.show');
Route::post('/images_update', [TestController::class, 'update'])->name('images.update');
```