# API: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel

When i send with postman i got this error message: "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

api.php

```
  Route::post('/coproprietaires/store_api','App\Http\Controllers\CoproprietaireController@store_api');
```

my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Coproprietaire;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class CoproprietaireController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class CoproprietaireController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store_api(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate(Coproprietaire::$rules);

        request()->validate(Lot::$rules);
        $coproprietaire = Coproprietaire::create($request->all());
        $lot = Lot::create($request->all());
        $coproprietaire->lots()->save($lot);

        

        if ($coproprietaire)
        {
            return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the list `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Answer (score 0):

With the `php artisan route:list` you should first see the list of routes. From there you will see which method you should use the function you are using. You should use the method you see there while determining your routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using laravel 8, then there is a different procedure to use routes.

Goto your routes files and declare this code at top of the file.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
Route::post('/coproprietaires/store_api',[CoproprietaireController::class , 'store_api']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes, make sure that the route you are hitting has the appropriate method and request type.

In my case, I was not adding the "**api**" prefix before my axios request. Like this:

```
axios.post('api/search/items',data)
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
})
.catch(function(){
  console.log(response)
})
```

Also, if the request is POST and includes files, don't forget to include mutlipart/form-data.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this,

```
Route::post('coproprietaires/store_api','App\Http\Controllers\CoproprietaireController@store_api');
```

You don't need to prefix your route with `/`.

And also run
`php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan route:cache`.

And also check your route url using `php artisan route:list`.