# i am getting this error for deleting a record, detail issue is below. " The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. "

Tags: laravel

I am deleting a record and getting the above error but when I go back the record is deleted. Why I am getting an error if the record is deleted when I go back? I tried solving like this: this is my view blade page route

```
<a href='/DeleteCandidateID/{{$candidate_id->id}}'><i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i></a>
```

I tried this as well:

form method as well but getting same answer

and this is my web.php

```
Route::post('/DeleteCandidateID/{CanDelID}', 'CandidateController@DeleteCandidateID')->name('candidate.DeleteCandidateID');
```

this is my controller :

```
 public function DeleteCandidateID($CanDelID) {

    $canid = Candidate::findOrFail($CanDelID)->delete();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'candidate deleted successfully');
}
```

Comment: It's better if you past your code instead of image ^^

Comment: ok i am going to upload code

Comment: i have used all cache methods but still not solved the problem, I have uploaded the code

Comment: Ok thanks :) I added an answer, I hope it's good ? What do you mean with "cache methods" ?

Comment: cache:clear, i tried, hi thanks for the answer but I tried form method as well and simple links as well before but getting the same answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Comment: hi @matiaslauriti , i tried but issue not solved, the error is there by click on delete button, but when I go back the record is deleted

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST POSSIBILITY :**

You added a simple link and in your routes file you indicated that you are waiting a POST request, so you need to add a form in your blade view with the POST method:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('candidate.DeleteCandidateID', ['CanDelID' => $candidate_id->id]) }}">
   <button type="submit">Delete the candidate</button>
   @csrf
</form>
```

---

**SECOND POSSIBILITY :**

Following [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/the-get-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-post), if the problem still persists, you can try to keep your link :

```
<a href='/DeleteCandidateID/{{$candidate_id->id}}'><i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg text-danger"></i></a>
```

And change `Route::post(...)` to `Route::get(...)`. I think it can fix your problem but it's definilty not the best way.

---

**THIRD POSSIBILITY :**

Overide the POST method with `method_field` :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('candidate.DeleteCandidateID', ['CanDelID' => $candidate_id->id]) }}">
   <button type="submit">Delete the candidate</button>
   @csrf
   {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
```

And change your route to : `Route::delete(...)`

Comment: hi thanks but  fist it showed " undefined canIDid" which I removed but when I clicked on " delete the candidate" it is again showing this error 
 
**The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST** . but when I go back the record deleted, but on clicking on delete the error is still tehre

Comment: Oops I did a mistake sorry, it was not $canIDid but 'canIDid' as parameter, I edited my post ^^

Comment: hi , i am getting the same error by putting :  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('candidate.DeleteCandidateID', [ 'CanDelID' => $candidate_id->id]) }}">
   <button type="submit">Delete the candidate</button>
   @csrf
            </form>

Comment: @MohsinKhan I edited my post with a second possibility

Comment: hi, thanks for support but sorry the error is like this now **The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.** and the not even the record is deleting with this

Comment: If you use the second possibility, you need to keep your simple link and not use my form in the first possibility, @MohsinKhan I edited my post

Comment: i tried but not working, but thanks for your time and support, I will look into it more in deep. Thanks @jerome

Comment: @MohsinKhan I added a third possibility

Comment: @MohsinKhan did you find a way to fix the problem ?

Comment: Thanks for the 3rd possibility,

Answer (score 1):

- Your route should use `delete` method. Run php artisan route:list to confirm that.

  `Route::Delete('/DeleteCandidateID/{CanDelID}','CandidateController@DeleteCandidateID')->name('candidate.DeleteCandidateID');`
- Use a form to delete

  ```
  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('candidate.DeleteCandidateID', $idOfTheCandidate) }}">
            @csrf
            @method('delete')
            <button type="submit">Delete the candidate</button>
        </form>
  ```
- That should work and note `@method('delete')` in the form. Browsers do not understand delete an put methods, so we place it there and it will override post method when the server is hit.

Comment: This somehow solved my problem

Comment: Great, kindly remember to accept my answer if it solved your problem. Happy coding!