# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE. Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

hello i have a problem with uploading a form this is my form

```
@extends('layouts.app-admin')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>Subir Accesorio</h1>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{ 'admin.files.store' }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Nombre Producto') }}</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="precio"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Precio Producto') }}</label>
                            <input type="number" name="precioUnitario">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="stock"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Stock Producto') }}</label>
                            <input type="number" name="stock">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="descripcion"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Descripcion Producto') }}</label>
                            <input type="text" name="descripcion">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usuario"
                                class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Imagen Producto') }}</label>
                            <input type="file" name="imagen" id="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12 ">Subir Productos</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my web.php is

```
Route::resource('/admin/files', FileController::class)->names('admin.files');
```

and controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\File;

class FileController extends Controller
{
    /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.files.index');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('admin.files.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($file)
{
    return view('admin.files.show');
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($file)
{
    return view('admin.files.edit');
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $file)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($file)
{
    //
}
}
```

and if I use the r command r:l

```
GET|HEAD        admin ...................... admin.principal › Admin\PrincipalController@principal 
  GET|HEAD        admin/files ....................... admin.files.index › Admin\FileController@index 
  POST            admin/files ....................... admin.files.store › Admin\FileController@store 
  GET|HEAD        admin/files/create .............. admin.files.create › Admin\FileController@create 
  GET|HEAD        admin/files/{file} .................. admin.files.show › Admin\FileController@show 
  PUT|PATCH       admin/files/{file} .............. admin.files.update › Admin\FileController@update  
  DELETE          admin/files/{file} ............ admin.files.destroy › Admin\FileController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        admin/files/{file}/edit ............. admin.files.edit › Admin\FileController@edit
```

the problem is that the method POST is not supported but it is that in the route it uses POST and I don't know what to do I try several things but I can't find a solution and I don't advance my goal is to upload a product through a form

Comment: Can you check the network tab of the browser and see the exact route that is getting called? Because your routing seems correct overall.

Comment: `php artisan optimize` in case you forgot or `r:l` list directly from web.php without refreshing routes cache.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Answer (score 3):

Forgot to add route function on action attribute

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.files.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried to put it right with the route but it still doesn't work

the error remains the same

Comment: In this case please put the entire ERROR message so we can see if err it comes from "admin.files.store'" route or some other redirect

Answer (score 1):

Have had a similar problem. This is what I did try running this command

`php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

I had a smillier error ..try to check the following

1. the action name should be the same of route name :

action="{{ route('admin.files.store')}}

2)check that  you are using get to return  the view of form and then post when you send request

Comment: I reviewed and did what the previous partner told me, I added  
<form action="{{ route('admin.files.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
but the method GET do you mean this one

 public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.files.index');
    }

Comment: it works for me very good I have tried it it works . I did not use :                                            Route::resource('/admin/files', FileController::class)->names('admin.files');         instead I used Route::get('/admin/files', [FileController::class, 'create']);

    Route::post('/admin/files', [FileController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.files.store');
    always before post there be get to return the view of form . Tell me if it  is not working

Answer (score 0):

When working with resource controllers it is best practice to use the @method() helper INSIDE the respective views form to specify the the request method.

For example use the route list command to see what request method the endpoint accepts and then pass that parameter to the @method() function.

Example

@method(‘post’)