# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. But my method is post

Tags: php, laravel, api, post, get

I am new to Laravel and I am using Laravel as an API for my Angular project.
I have no problem when I am using the Laravel upon retrieving data using the `get` method but I have a big problem when inserting data into it using `post` method

I have the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

I swear this is my code at the `api.php`

```
<?php


use App\Models\sample;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Resources\SampleResource;
use App\Http\Controllers\SampleController;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});
//I tried to add this hoping it will work, it wont
Route::post('/sample', [SampleController::class, 'store']);
// Route::post('/sample', function(Request $request){
//     return sample::create($request->all);
// });
```

I have tried following the instructions in the link below hoping it would help me it wouldn't
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)
[this](https://laracasts.com/index.php/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/the-get-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-post)

Comment: in which api your getting this error can you mention that please

Comment: I assume that your request from angular has the `/api/` path right? `/api/sample`

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem, The GET method is not supported for this route and your back-end route is the post so when you hit this API you may not use the post method. You must need to use the post method for sending data to the backend. You can follow the below example in jquery but you have to apply it in your angular project context like Axios or anything else:

Client-side request =>

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{route('check_inventory_product')}}",
        data: data,
       success: function (response) { 
        console.log(response);
       }
  });
```

backend route =>

```
Route::post('check_inventory_product'[InventoryController::class,'check_inventory_product'])->name('check_inventory_product');
```

See here I used ajax request type POST and route method type post.

Comment: what was the name() for ?

Comment: @Bianxzy - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: Why do you give an example in jQuery when the OP states they are using Angular?

Comment: @M.Eriksson exactly

Comment: @M.Eriksson I just give him hints on how to solve the problems. As a developer, he should understand how to apply this logic in Angular or Vue js or anything else.

Comment: Developers with some experience, yes. But an answer shouldn't be a "hint" or "nudge". It should be a _solution_. If they just started out, they would now need to learn a completely different library (that's not even particularly relevant anymore), just to be able to use your answer. By your own standard, as a developer, you should be able to give an answer in Angular. Also remember that you have _no idea_ what knowledge level the OP, or any future visitors are at.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Nice observation. Is it true that those who started as beginners take hints for solving problems for solutions?

Comment: If a beginner search for a similar issue with angular and find this answer (based on angular being mentioned in the question), introducing irrelevant libraries would most likely just confuse them. They would need to learn that library just to be able to decipher your answer. And as I mentioned, answers should be solutions and not hints, regardless who reads it.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so here is the answer guys, this error is not an error at all after all. IF this oh so called "error" appear on my screen it only means that my API or routes are working I tried to call this one into my angular project and it worked!

SOMETIMES THIS IS NOT ERROR
THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR TIME

Comment: Hold on, are you saying that you tried to access the API endpoint in the browser directly and _not_ through angular when you got that error? If that's the case, you should have stated that in the question and you would have had an answer within minutes. Then everyone here could have moved on and helped other people instead of answering the wrong question. For next time, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include _all_ info from start.