# Laravel - duplicating the login page to function the same as the existing one

Tags: php, laravel

I'm very new to Laravel, so all of the things I have tried have just been from searching through the routes and files and looking for anything login related and trying to add the necessary code by intuiting what to use based on existing code, because I could not find any examples of how to do this from searching online.

I need to duplicate my login page so that I can put some necessary information at the top for whenever users are sent to the login page via another app.

So I duplicated my login page and just called it `app-login.blade php` and added the view, which lets me load the page and it looks normal.

```php
Route::view('app-login', 'theme::auth.app-login')->name('wave.app-login');
```

But when I try to log in here, I just get this error.

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
> Illuminate \ Routing \ AbstractRouteCollection: 118 methodNotAllowed

Honestly I would tell you all the things I've tried, but I cannot even remember most of them to tell you. Just adding things that looked like they might work by using existing login related code that I see and duplicating it and trying to make it work for my new login page name, but I have no clue which if them were or were not on the right track.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I just need this login page to perform identically to the default one, only with a couple text-based additions I've made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178647/the-post-method-is-not-supported-for-this-route-supported-methods-get-head-l)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Maybe i'm just too  inexperienced still, but it seemed like having to change anything along those lines shouldn't be necessary because I  want the page to function exactly how the existing one does, only with a new name and some text added. So in theory, changing that should not be what I need to fix the problem, but i'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

The form of the login page is likely submitting (`POST`ing) to itself. So at the start, there were 2 routes namely:

- `GET /login`
- `POST /login`

You have now duplicated the `GET` route as `GET /app-login` which I assume has the same `<form>` which submits to itself, so it sends to `POST /app-login`.

You have to change the route the form posts to, so it makes the same action as the original login page.

Comment: This makes total sense, I'll give this a go and see if I can figure out how to modify this to fix the error. Thank you very much